# form post to database as well as paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I've got a form, which when submitted collects the data and writes the values of the fields within my database. The form uses a post request to a response page which then connects to the database and posts all the fields necessary to my db.

I've also got a radiobuttons called payment and one of the options is paypal. My goal is to end up posting the fields to the db but also post the form data below to my paypal account in one go

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="myemails" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Digital Download" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="9.99" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://myurl/form.htm" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://myurl/example/ipn.php" />
<input type="image" src="btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Paypal" />
</form>
```

I know I can use the following command below to do a redirect to another page which has a form

```
if($_REQUEST['payment']=="Paypal") { redirect to another page with the code above, but the user has to click on submit again}
```

However I would just like the user to click on submit once and the my db records the details and then automatically redirects them to paypal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty trivial, just do:

```
if($_POST['submit']) {
    // save the POSTed data to the DB
}

// now for PayPal
if($_POST['payment'] == "Paypal") {
    // now connect to PayPal API and process a payment
}
```

I'd recommend fogetting about `$_REQUEST` and using **ONLY** `$_GET` and/or `$_POST` where needed.

Comment: why forget about $_request?

Comment: @fdreger It is a potential hole and allows attacker to perform attack more easily...

Comment: This seems like the best way to do it, except the ipn class I am using doesn't look like it uses the Paypal API [link](http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal-ipn-with-php.html)

Comment: @shadyyx: why a potential hole? Many technologies (including most of Java web frameworks) do not use separate APIs for parameters coming from different sources, and it is not considered bad by anyone. Your application is either XSRF resistant or not, using $_POST instead of $_REQUEST does not make it more secure.

Comment: @fdreger Using directly POST or GET where applicable is a step way closer to implement XSRF. Especially in a case when You need to be able to receive only POST requests (even from other sites/applications) - then not accepting also the GET request is like closing the backdoor for possible attack (sure the attacker could use picklocks to open it ;-) - but it is making it a little more difficult).

Answer (score -1):

Not sure to understand your question but you should create the temporary data into your database on the page loading and when the paypal api callback call your inp.php, transform your temporary data in a validated one

Comment: I want to store the Booking details of a person regardless whether they are using paypal to make the payment or some other manual way. Hence my response page records the details of the person that is making the enquiry, I then want it to redirect to the paypal website (providing paypal is chosen in payment option) - but sounds like I need to use the api to do this and not the 'form' method